# Returning PageResult from WebAPI not formatting as OData

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm attempting to migrate a WebAPI-based app from WebAPI RC to the release version. It takes in some query parameters, and returns ATOM-formatted OData. Since it's a running service, I need to maintain the current behavior.

I've changed the API methods to return a `PageResult<T>` with my data in it. According to the *[Supporting OData Query Options](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options)* article on MSDN that should be all I need to do, but it's not working. I get the result, but it's always formatted as JSON. I've tried changing the `Accept` request header to `application/atom+xml`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I've also tried adding the following lines in my `WebApiConfig` to no apparent effect:

```
configuration.EnableQuerySupport();
configuration.Formatters.InsertRange(0, ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create());
```

I tried clearing out the existing formatters, just to see what would happen. I just get back `406 Not Acceptable` errors. So it seems like perhaps the OData formatters are not reporting that they can handle the request/response?

Comment: Have you installed the Web API OData components? These are available through NuGet.

Comment: Yes, I grabbed the latest from NuGet yesterday.

Comment: Have you added the `Queryable` ([Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
) attribute to your controller method and set it's return type to `IQueryable<T>`? Maybe you could post your controller and global.asax code.

Comment: I'm not returning an `IQueryable<T>` because I need to return a $skiptoken, and my understanding is that you can't do that with an `IQueryable<T>`. Hence use of `PageResult<T>` instead. My function code is irrelevant, lots of proprietary data access. I can repro the problem with a dummy method that just returns `new PageResult<string>(new List<string>(), null, null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this blog post to learn about enabling OData:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/29/getting-started-with-asp-net-webapi-odata-in-3-simple-steps.aspx

You're missing an OData route - the route is required for the formatter to work.

Comment: Unfortunately `MapODataRoute()` doesn't let me define any defaults, which I need to do for legacy reasons. My controllers also don't conform to the pattern, again for legacy reasons. Is there any way I can get the OData formatters without rewriting everything?

Comment: Well, that was the solution, but it required basically rebuilding the entire application.

Comment: Is this still the "accepted" way you did it?  This is AN answer that i have found but, like you said... there are reasons why we would like to use map routes